# how to create a list of object using json in Angular?

Tags: json, typescript, angular-cli

Hi I'd like to create a small authentication service in my angular application, I have a JSON file containing the information about my users:

```
{
  "Users": [
    {
      "type":"teacher",
      "id":0,
      "name":"TEACHER ONE",
      "login":"tone",
      "password":"d450c5dbcc10db0749277efc32f15f9f"
    },
    {
      "type":"student",
      "id":1,
      "name":"STUDENT ONE",
      "login":"sone",
      "password":"ec80dcc5a3eab73a4f128b66c1e4b92a"
    },
    {
      "type":"student",
      "id":2,
      "name":"STUDENT TWO",
      "login":"stwo",
      "password":"62e73bf0deb1871860702b064106f1dc"
    }
  ]
}
```

and here's what I try for my authentifiaction

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as users from '../assets/Users.json';
import { clientType } from "./clientType";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class user {
  $type: clientType; //I put a dollar so equals won't compare this property
  $id: number; //I put a dollar so equals won't compare this property
  $name: string; //I put a dollar so equals won't compare this property
  login: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(type: clientType, id: number, name: string, login: string, password: string) {
    this.$type = type;
    this.$id = id;
    this.$name = name;
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
  }


}

export class AuthService {
  private userList: /*don't know what to put*/ = /*don't know what to put*/;
  constructor() { }
  consultData( ): void{
  }

  returnUsers() {
    return this.userList;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get an array of users using my JSON file but I don't know how to extract the JSON object as `user` objects, can someone help me finding how ?

Comment: `private userList: user[] = users as user[];`? Note that typically class names begin with an upper case character.

Comment: thank you for the uppercase but now typescript is throwing an
 `Error:(28, 30) TS2352: Conversion of type '{ "Users": { "type": string; "id": number; "name": string; "login": string; "password": string; }[]; }' to type 'User[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ "Users": { "type": string; "id": number; "name": string; "login": string; "password": string; }[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'User[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.`

Comment: Oh, right, use `= users.Users as user[];`